# How to update XML file with lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I want to update xml file with new information by using lxml library.
For example, I have this code:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>>
>>> tree = etree.parse('books.xml')
```

where 'books.xml' file, has this content: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/books.xml

I want to update this file with new book:

```
>>> new_entry = etree.fromstring('''<book category="web" cover="paperback">
... <title lang="en">Learning XML 2</title>
... <author>Erik Ray</author>
... <year>2006</year>
... <price>49.95</price>
... </book>''')
```

My question is, how can I update `tree` element tree with `new_entry` tree and save the file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go, get the root of the tree, append your new element, save the tree as a string to a file:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('books.xml')

new_entry = etree.fromstring('''<book category="web" cover="paperback">
<title lang="en">Learning XML 2</title>
<author>Erik Ray</author>
<year>2006</year>
<price>49.95</price>
</book>''')

root = tree.getroot()

root.append(new_entry)

f = open('books-mod.xml', 'wb')
f.write(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
f.close()
```

Comment: pretty_print=True is not working for appended nodes.

Comment: The last part of this code is not working for me. `etree.tostring()` returns `bytes` and so `f.write()` throws the following exception: `TypeError, write() argument must be str, not bytes`.
I suggest to either convert `bytes` to `string` adding `.decode("utf-8")` at the end of `etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)`, or use the `ElementTree.write()` method in this way `tree.write("new/file/path")`. While the first snippet updates an existing file, while te second one creates a new file, but both can be used for the purpose of this question.

Comment: The most simple change make the code work is to change the line

    f = open('books-mod.xml', 'w')

to

    f = open('books-mod.xml', 'wb')

Comment: @Salvatore: you can use `etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, encoding=str)`

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, therefore I'll write an answer...

The most simple change make the code of Guillaume work is to change the line

```
f = open('books-mod.xml', 'w')
```

to

```
f = open('books-mod.xml', 'wb')
```